# How open front camera on Android and iOS and take a picture working with Vue.Js?

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js

I'm working on a PWA Vue.Js application and I need to take a user picture with the front camera on mobile.

I already did some code work on my desktop browser but I got no success making it working on mobile.

Here is the I tried so far:

```
<template>
  <div id="camera">
    <div>
      <video ref="video" id="video" width="100%" height="100%" autoplay/>
    </div>
    <div>
      <button id="snap" v-on:click="capture()">Snap Photo</button>
    </div>
    <canvas ref="canvas" id="canvas" width="100%" height="100%"/>>
  </div>
</template>






<script>

export default {
  name: 'Camera',
  data() {
    return {
      video: {},
      canvas: {},
      captures: []
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.video = this.$refs.video;
    if(navigator.mediaDevices && navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia) {
        navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: true }).then(stream => {
             video.srcObject = stream;
                video.play();
                video.onplay = function () {
                };
                this.video.play();
        });
    }
},
  methods: {
    capture() {
        this.canvas = this.$refs.canvas;
        var context = this.canvas.getContext("2d").drawImage(this.video, 0, 0, 640, 480);
        this.captures.push(canvas.toDataURL("image/webp"));
    }
}
}
</script>






<style>
    #camera {
        text-align: center;
        color: #2c3e50;
    }
    #video {
        background-color: #000000;
    }
    #canvas {
        display: none;
    }
    li {
        display: inline;
        padding: 5px;
    }
</style>
```

What I should do to make it work on mobile?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

why you use button you follow **html 5 tags** it will work:

```
<input type="file" accept="image/*" capture="camera" />
```

Comment: It should actually be either "user" or "environment". See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/capture. Using "camera" just acts as a boolean value, which is now depriacted in favour of "user"/"environment"